# Accessing a serial device from LXC guest

Tags: devices, lxc, cgroups, container

I have a Fedora 26 host running a privileged Ubuntu 16.04 guest in an LXC container. My goal is to connect to a serial device (`/dev/ttyACM0`) from the LXC guest.

I created the guest OS with the following command:

   `sudo lxc-create -t download -n ubuntu-c -- -d ubuntu -r xenial -a amd64`

From the host OS the device shows up as:

   `ls -la /dev/ttyACM0 
   crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 166, 0 Aug 18 14:52 /dev/ttyACM0`

After starting the container, I do not see `/dev/ttyACM0` listed  so I run this command on the host:

   `$sudo lxc-device -n ubuntu-c add /dev/ttyACM0`

The device then appears under `/dev` in the container.

I tried to open the device with `minicom` but get a permission error. So I tried adding the device to the `cgroups` setting for the container by running command on the host:

   `$ sudo lxc-cgroup -n ubuntu-c devices.allow "c 166:* rwm"`

Still had a permission error so I also tried to be more specific with:

   `$ sudo lxc-cgroup -n ubuntu-c devices.allow "c 166:0 rwm"`

And verified that the command worked with:

   `$ sudo lxc-cgroup -n ubuntu-c devices.list
   c *:* m
   b *:* m
   c 1:3 rwm
   c 1:5 rwm
   c 1:7 rwm
   c 5:0 rwm
   c 5:1 rwm
   c 5:2 rwm
   c 1:8 rwm
   c 1:9 rwm
   c 136:* rwm
   c 10:229 rwm
   c 254:0 rm
   c 10:200 rwm
   c 10:228 rwm
   c 10:232 rwm
   c 166:* rwm
   c 166:0 rwm`

But still, I can't access the device. I should say that I started the container as root, and I am the root user inside the container when trying to access the device. I have also tried adding `lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 166:* rwm` to the file `/var/lib/lxc/ubuntu-c/config` with no success.